# How to prevent over-write bootstrap rows?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[This is the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC69C.png)
I need to prevent over-write rows using bootstrap 3. This is my code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Location</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.location}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Salary</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.salaryDetails}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Recruiter</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.location}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="container col-md-4">
                            <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.location}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need set auto height in every rows by bootstrap 3.

Comment: Can you post whole HTML code? The problem may be in _rows_ that are _form-groups_ and _columns_ that are _containers_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the .row class with properties from the form-group class.
Change all of your input rows.

from

```
<div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-4">
       <label class="control-label">Location</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.location}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
           <label class="control-label">Location</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <label class="control-label">{{draftJobPost.location}}</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap-Clearfix attribute.
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/